# Wrapped text expanding a div, despite using display:inline-block and setting a max-width

Tags: html, css

Simple problem that *should* be easy to fix, but I can't find a solution.

I'm trying to "shrink-wrap" a div to its contents by setting a `max-width` and using `display: inline-block`, which seems to be the standard method.

However, whenever a word causes the text to wrap (i.e. it has reached the `max-width` threshold), white space is shown where the text *would have* been, even though it isn't actually there.

This [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gdyt7mg7/) demonstrates what I'm talking about.

I've searched high and low to find a solution, and the closest I've found is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14597951/3494677), although I really don't want to go down that route.

Is there really not a simple, clean, CSS-only solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A jQuery Assisted Solution**

What you need cannot be done with CSS alone, but it is relatively easy to do so using jQuery.

Since `#mySpan` in an inline element, its width will be exactly the width of the text before any of the lines wrap.

Use jQuery to probe the length of the inner `span` and use that value to set the width of the parent element.

Depending on the max-length of the parent block and the distribution of word lengths in the text, you may still get some ugly white space on the ragged right edge of the block.

Regardless, this is a useful trick to keep in mind.

```js
$('#myDiv').innerWidth($('#mySpan').innerWidth());
```

```css
#myDiv {
    background-color: red;
    max-width: 410px;
}
#mySpan {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv">
    <span id="mySpan">Here is some text. Why does a wrapped word create space and where the word would have been on the previous line?</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, Marc. While I was hoping to not use JavaScript to achieve the result, your solution is simple and elegant, and as you mentioned, it seems there is no way of achieving this with CSS alone.