# Parent div with max-width doesn't fit according to its child span (pure CSS)

Tags: css

I'm trying to draw box (DIV) with max-width and child span.
Somehow the parent DIV stretches to its max width, not the size of its child.

As you see on the pic, the size of child span is 258, but the DIV is still 300:

[image]

How to make DIV width equal to its child (= 258 + border)?

```css
.borderDiv {
    max-width: 300px;
    border: 1px solid #bebdbd;
}

.textSpan {

}
```

```html
<div class="borderDiv">
  <span class="textSpan">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</span>
</div>
```

I've tried inline-block, flex and border-box, it doesn' work.

Any ideas?

Comment: div elements display as [block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Block/CSS) by default, meaning they'll stretch as wide as they can.

Comment: the answer suggested as similar to this doesn't actually address this scenario where you want the container to shrink down to its child element width after it employed the word wrapping. So it's wrong. Nor `max-content` nor `overflow: auto` nor `float: left` give any help on that achievement

Comment: @DiegoD That doesn't seem to be a pertinent part of the question, just a circumstance of the example, but I'll provide a target for that specific scenario as well.

Comment: @TylerH I commented like that because I put efforts while doing an answer and I happened to land on that question also when trying every combination. Those hints dind't go anywhere to solve the scenario shown here. To get there I had to do something different and if there's a better way to achieve that it means my answer is just wrong. That's why it's pretty important to me. I'll be glad to know the exact line that would match with this scenario and I'll remove my answer of course

Comment: @DiegoD I'm not sure what you're saying. That you put effort into an answer here doesn't impact whether the question has already been asked and answered elsewhere. The answer to the question OP asked here is "use display: inline-block". The answer to the question _not asked_ here but inferred by you is "you can't do that in CSS. That's how word-wrap is designed to work. Use JS instead." Of course, there might be a _new_ solution to that problem that works in CSS only, but if so it needs to be posted on that question, not on a new/duplicate one.

Comment: @AntonAntonoff the question was closed because there's another very similar question on SO but it actually, according to my humble opinion that could still be wrong, doesn't address your same scenario. On the other hand I made an attemp that I shared in my answer.. I didn't get any feedback yet. The point is that the span is sizing itself according to its parent that will go as large as it can following its max-width. So to remove that gap left with word wrapping you need tricks

Comment: @TylerH I think that's not what I said.. and if someone else said to use `display: inline-block`he was wrong because that alone doesn't solve the problem. Maybe the question requires deeper thinking to understand where the problem is. Maybe I explained in my previous comment the key better than I did in my answer

Comment: @DiegoD so "it's impossible with pure CSS" is also an aswer:)

Comment: @DiegoD display: inline-block ***does*** solve the problem. OP wants the parent div to shrink to the width of the child span. Display: inline-block is _the_ solution for when the parent is a div or other block element (or display: inline for inline elements).

Comment: it's close to impossible.. put in those terms.. since the size of the span is a consequence of the container that goes as large as 300px anyway. The container tells the span to go 300px width and the span word wraps.. but being an inline element, it will leave the gap. If you want the container to make a further action and shrink down where the span word wrapped, the css cannot help. If it can I'm still waiting to see how

Comment: no one shown how display inline block on the child will remove the gap left after word wrap.. I'm waiting to see it

Comment: @DiegoD The gap left after word-wrap is simply the symptom that made it clear to OP that their code is not working as they want. And in case _that_ is their question (which they didn't ask about), it is _also_ answered by the additional duplicates, as I mentioned already.

Comment: _How to make DIV width equal to its child (= 258 + border)?_ did I invent this part of the question? and didn't my answer just address exactly that part like no other did?

Comment: @DiegoD You are misunderstanding the question. The parenthetical mark is OP's observation of what the outcome of word-wrapping due to a 300px max-width limitation is, it's not the literal width goal of OP. Their stated goal is what comes before the parenthetical.

Comment: @TylerH I'm very sure the OP was actually asking what he asked.. and I already highlighted the actual question quoted literally. But I didn't mean to discuss my answer here on comments. It was a side effect of an escalation began with an innocent comment I did to just say that the similar questions shown were not even close to this one. But I get the point. In the end there's no answer if not explaining why it can't be done exactly as asked. I retracted the vote to reopen because there's nothing to add. The sad part is an OP not having any role in this if not the question itself

Answer (score 0):

you can use max-width:fit-content;. You can also keep max-width:300px if needed (instead of fit-content). Pls note that the word won't be broken, so if a word can't be fitted you will still have space. (otherwise you can use as well in .textSpan the word-break: break-all;

```css
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.borderDiv {
  max-width: fit-content;
  border: 1px solid #bebdbd;
}

/*
.textSpan{
  max-width: fit-content;
  word-break: break-all;
}
*/
```

```html
<div class="borderDiv">
    <span class="textSpan">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sunt, expedita?</span>
  </div>
```

Comment: the point is to limit the DIVs max width at 300px

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the width for the inner div and make the outer div an inline block or change the width of the outer div to 260px with border-box.

```css
.borderDiv {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    max-width: 260px;
    border: 1px solid #bebdbd;
}

.textSpan {

}
```

```html
<div class="borderDiv">
  <span class="textSpan">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Text can change, text size is not a constant value. But the box must be not more than 300px

Answer (score 0):

You can set the width to `min-content`, `max-content` or `fit-content`. These are slightly different but fairly self-explanatory but there's a useful explainer on [logrocket](https://blog.logrocket.com/understanding-min-content-max-content-fit-content-css/).  If you want the div to shrink to the content but not exceed 300px then set the `width` as above then `max-width` to 300px as below:

```css
.borderDiv {
    max-width: 300px;
    width: fit-content;
    border: 1px solid #bebdbd;
}
```

```html
Example 1
<div class="borderDiv">
  <span class="textSpan">Short - div shrinks</span>
</div>
<br>
Example 2
<div class="borderDiv">
  <span class="textSpan">This is really long so 300px will be reached and max-width kicks in. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</span>
</div>
```

Comment: In "Example 2" text span is 282px, but div is still 300

Comment: Ahh.. I see what you're trying to do now. Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14596213/12571484)

Answer (score 0):

A very stretched solution to make the div (block element) stretch to its content size (despite it being an inline element and thus not having an actual size but just phrasal content) it's styling the parent container with `width: min-content` so that it will go as down as possible with its min width and yet enlarge according to the very subtle wrapping hint made with the `<wbr>` element put there for sizing reasons (otherwise you'll need to style the span as `inline-block` and give precise size to hint the wrap). For the wrapping to be forced like that requires the span to be styled with `white-space: nowrap;`.

The main reason why I posted this answer it's to show both the power of `min-content` and more importantly the lesser known `<wbr>`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/wbr

```css
div {
  width: min-content;
  max-width: 300px;
  
  border: solid 1px;
}

span {
  white-space: nowrap;
  
  border: dashed 1px red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur<wbr /> adipiscing elit</span>
</div>
```

I'm quite sure there's no way to go further than this with css only.. the other solution would be to process the elements on document ready and resize the container using the actual content width rendered. Like you tried, the span is wrapping its text according to the container max width but will leave a white gap anyway otherwise.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',()=>{  
  const target = document.querySelector('div > span');  
  const actualWidth = target.offsetWidth;  
  target.parentElement.style.width = `${actualWidth}px`;        
});
```

```css
div {
    max-width: 300px;
    border: 1px solid #bebdbd;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</span>
</div>
```